# I keep getting this Heroku error when I use my discord.py bot. I am using a github repo for heroku, not the toolbelt

Tags: python, github, heroku, discord.py

I keep getting this error while making my code:

```
 -----> Python app detected
 !     Requested runtime (python-3.5.2) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

My code:

```
# import

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

# variables
token = 'Nope'
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>', help_command=None) 

# events

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    print('-----------------------')
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Game(name="version 1.7.9 | >help"))
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if str (message.channel) == "media-only" and message.content !="":
        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
    await client.process_commands(message)

# help command

@client.command()
async def help(ctx, command=None):
    if command == None:
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Help", description="Do >help (command) to get help on the specific command", color=0x00ffee)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/708327158346547350/785864075829575711/e.jpg")
        embed.add_field(name="ping", value="Shows the bot's current speed", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="help", value="Shows this page.", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="support", value="Invites you to the bot's [server](link).", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="invite", value="Sends you a [link](link) to invite the bot", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="servers", value="Says the amount of servers the bot is currently in", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="site", value="Sends the link to the bot's [website](link)")
        embed.add_field(name="beta", value="Sends [invite](link) for Amaze Beta", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="modhelp", value="Sends the help page for moderators and admins", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="This bot's prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
    elif command == "ping":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Ping Help", description="Shows the bot's current speed", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Usage:", value=">ping", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    elif command == "support":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Support Help", description="Sends support link", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Usage:", value=">support", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    elif command == "invite":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Invite Help", description="Sends you the bot invite", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Usage:", value=">invite", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    elif command == "servers":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Servers Help", description="Shows the amount of servers the bot is in", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Usage:", value=">servers", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    elif command == "site":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Site help", description="Sends the link to the bot's [website](link)")
        embed.add_field(name="Usage:", value=">site")
        embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    elif command == "beta":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Beta help", description="Sends [invite](link) for Amaze Beta")
        embed.add_field(name="Usage:", value=">beta")
        embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129")
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    elif command == "ban":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Ban Help", description="Bans someone", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Usage:", value=">ban (user) (reason) | reason is optional", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    elif command == "kick":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Kick Help", description="Kicks someone", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Usage:", value=">kick (user) (reason) | reason is optional", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    elif command == "purge":
        embed=discord.Embed(title="Purge Help", description="Purges certain amount of messages in a channel", inline=False)
        embed.add_field(name="Usage:", value=">purge (amount) | Amount is optional, and if there is no amount, it automatically purges all messages in a channel", inline=False)
        embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f"Command `{command}` not found, please try again with a different command")
@client.command()
async def modhelp(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Mod Help", description="Only moderators and admins can use these commands", color=0x00ffee)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="link")
    embed.add_field(name="ban", value="bans mentioned member", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="kick", value="kicks mentioned member", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="purge", value="purges selected amount of messages in a channel", inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text="Prefix is > | Made by TristanDaSavage#9129 :)")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(':a_:786988781056163880')
    await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)

# commands

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'The current bot speed is {round(client.latency * 1000)} ms')
@client.command()
async def support(ctx):
    await ctx.send("The support server is link")
@client.command()
async def invite(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Invite the bot at link")
@client.command()
async def servers(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"I am currently in {len(client.guilds)} servers")
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def ban (ctx, member:discord.User=None, *, reason =None):
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("You cannot ban yourself")
        return
    if reason == None:
        reason = "undefined reason"
    message = f"You have been banned from **{ctx.guild.name}** for *{reason}*"
    try:
        await member.send(message)
        await ctx.guild.ban(member, reason=reason)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} has been banned for *{reason}*!")
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send('I do not have permissions, please go to my role under settings and enable administrator, and/or move my role to the top so i have permission')
    except:
        await ctx.guild.kick(member, reason=reason)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Could not send message to {member}, but banned anyways")
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick (ctx, member:discord.User=None, *, reason =None):
    if member == None or member == ctx.message.author:
        await ctx.channel.send("You cannot kick yourself")
        return
    if reason == None:
        reason = "undefined reason"
    message = f"You have been kicked from **{ctx.guild.name}** for *{reason}*"
    try:
        await member.send(message)
        await ctx.guild.kick(member, reason=reason)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} has been kicked for *{reason}*!")
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send('I do not have permissions, please go to my role under settings and enable administrator, and/or move my role to the top so i have permission')
    except:
        await ctx.guild.kick(member, reason=reason)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"Could not send message to {member}, but kicked anyways")
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount: int=None):
    try:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        if amount == None:
            await ctx.send('Successfully purged all messages!')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'Successfully purged {amount} messages!')
    except discord.Forbidden:
        await ctx.send('I do not have permissions, please go to my role under settings and enable administrator, and/or move my role to the top so i have permission')
@client.command()
async def site(ctx):
    await ctx.send("My website is link")
@client.command()
async def beta(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Amaze Beta's invite is link")

client.run(token)
```

btw the reason I had to put "link" everywhere is cuz it wouldn't let me ask this question with links for some reason.
Also, when I first got this error, I made a runtime.txt and stuff, but it still didn't work, so I deleted those files. Also, I tried installing the Heroku/python buildpack via both toolbelt and dashboard, and that also gave an error that I can't remember lol.

Comment: Ensure that the `runtime.txt` (if you have created one), `Procfile`, and `requirements.txt` are in the root directory. Can you share what you've put inside of them?

Comment: @Cloud I had made the runtime.txt and requirements.txt in the past when I was experiencing this issue the first time, and when they didn't work, I deleted them, but I never tried Procfile yet, which is probably why I got the error when I had the runtime and requirements. Can you please tell me what to put in the runtime, procfile, and requirements? Sorry, I'm just not very used to Heroku or anything because I never really use it, and even when I do use it, I usually don't need any of those files.

Comment: Take a look at [this complete tutorial](https://dev.to/p014ri5/making-and-deploying-discord-bot-with-python-4hep) or look into how to set a worker in a Procfile.

Comment: @Cloud I did that, and it worked and everything, but it didn't actually start my bot. I did the worker and stuff, but it wouldn't actually start the bot, and instead, it just stayed offline. The same thing happened to my previous bot after I uploaded it to Heroku, and I had thought that was just an error in my code, but with this reappearance of the issue, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Also, in runtime.txt I put python-3.8.2, in requirements.txt, I put discord.py, and in Procfile, I put worker: python bot/main.py

Comment: I think you have to ping your bot to keep it online in Heroku as it is actually meant for web apps. I recommend getting an actual VPS for Discord bots.

Comment: @Cloud it doesn't even go on in the first place tho. Should I use something like https://uptimerobot.com?

Comment: I think that is necessary.

Comment: how do i get my heroku server or whatever?

Comment: I linked a [pretty comprehensive tutorial](https://dev.to/p014ri5/making-and-deploying-discord-bot-with-python-4hep) 6 days ago.

Comment: @Cloud I did that tutorial already that's why I'm still asking why it's not working